# Visual C++ - Exclude file from Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, linker, visual-studio-2017

I have a Visual Studio solution with multiple C++ projects, and I find managing the linker dependencies a bit cumbersome.

Every time I include a header file from an other project, I need to explicitly add the corresponding `.obj` file in the linker settings.
I.e. in Properties>Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies:

```
..\Project1\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\Obj1.obj
..\Project1\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\Obj2.obj
..\Project2\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\Obj3.obj
..\Project2\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\Obj4.obj
```

Using wildcard characters would greatly simplify this task:

```
..\Project1\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\*.obj
..\Project2\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\*.obj
```

But unfortunately this also includes the two `main.obj` files from `Project1` and `Project2`.

**Is there a way to exclude these files from the linker input?**

I tried to use the standard(?) Windows file-search options like this:

```
"..\Project1\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\*.obj"-"..\Project1\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\main.obj"
"..\Project2\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\*.obj"-"..\Project2\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\main.obj"
```

but apparently they are not supported here. In fact, it seems simply adding quotes around a valid linker path breaks everything.

I've also seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410167/visual-studio-2012-exclude-compiled-file-from-linking), and sure, I could do something like this, renaming or deleting the undesired files by a custom script, but I'd prefer to avoid it. What I want to do seems like a fairly reasonable thing; every project having its own `main.obj` makes sense to me, linking some but not all `.obj`s makes sense to me as well. There must be some standard VS way to say "link everthing, except for this one" to the linker.

But feel free to correct me of course, that's why I'm here. Thanks in advance.

p.s.: I'm currently using VS2012, but I'm interested in answers for any VS version, even for older ones (I won't downgrade just for this, but I am interested).

Comment: Have you tried `..\Project1\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\O*.obj`?

Comment: Yes, that would be a good solution for the concrete example I specified, but unfortunately my actual filenames are more diverse, like Geometry.obj and AbstractPartitioner.obj.
But I'd be fine with this approach. Do you know if there are other wildcard characters allowed? Could I write something like ?????*.obj to exclude filenames shorter than 5 characters? Or do you know where could I find a list of allowed wildcards?

Comment: Usually the other object files will be part of a library, and you link against that. Otherwise you can add the .cpp file to the new project, without moving it from its original place. That way it will be included automatically.

Comment: Hm... so that's what I'm doing wrong.
Thank you for your help, I guess I'm gonna link against a lib then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**VS2013**:

I believe the way this is normally achieved by adding a reference to the other project which is building as a StaticLibrary or DynamicLibrary.

[This is done by right clicking on the parent project in the Solution Explorer and navigating to Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY9Uu.png)

**Add->References...**

[then selecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOsu4.png)

**Add New Reference...**

and selecting the checkbox.

You can then break up your code into different Static and Dynamic libraries based on what you need.

I hope this helps, I do not usually manually reference object files in the project files.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'd prefer to keep this question open for a little longer if you don't mind, but I'm gonna accept your answer unless I get an other one that directly solves my problem.

Comment: There is always more than one way to make something work :)